# Comparison between NewRelic and Azure Insights

Tags: azure, newrelic, azure-application-insights

I'm looking into using a performance and monitoring tool for my web application hosted on Azure.

I was wondering what the main differences are between Microsoft's **Application Insights** and **New Relic**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are many feature differences between the two products and such comparisons are usually subjective in nature. The following key themes are noted by customers as particular strengths of App Insights, when compared to New Relic:

- Developer-centric approach - SDK that rides with an app (as opposed to an agent installed aside of an app), provides better flexibility and control for developers; easier support for deployment, auto-scaling. See more [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/05/26/natural-evolution-of-application-performance-management/)
- Rich, open sourced SDKs – see [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/06/25/announcing-the-1-0-0-release-of-application-insights-windows-sdks/)
- Integrated with Visual Studio & Azure Developer Workflow
- Single product to collect and correlate all 360 degree data, including integrated Usage Analytics (beyond RUM) and Log Search; powerful and intuitive multi-dimensional analysis with drill-through into raw data
- Cloud friendlier pricing model

(Disclaimer: the answerer lists themselves as "Architect in Visual Studio Application Insights team".)

Comment: (agreed, but i'd put it as a comment on the question for posterity's sake.  "this is a subjective question, but in my opinion... <this content>" )

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider this a bad question, I searched for a feature comparisson and found none, that's why I resorted to StackOverflow.

Comment: I came here from a Google search and found my answer, so no, this is not a bad question.

Comment: You should at least note in your answer that you're working on the application insights team, so that readers know that this is a biased answer.

Comment: This post looks like spam.  I know it's not intended to be, and it is a good answer to the question, but [you're required to disclose your affiliation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) with Visual Studio Application Insights.  Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31263791/edit) your answer to include a disclaimer?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry folks, I somehow missed the last two comments, which were spot on. It was not intended, never tried to hide it, it appears in my profile. Still, it is a good practice, so will be more mindful in the future. Thank you!
I just saw that @Brad Larson added the proper disclaimer, thank you Brad!

Comment: Its been two years since the original answer.  I would have expected some rep from New Relic to respond in kind.

Comment: There's a difference between a "bad" question and one that's off-topic for SO, which this one certainly is. I'm surprised it's been allowed to remain open for this long.